# Large dataset and winforms

Tags: winforms, dataset

I have a dataset which is about 3 million records, and I would like to load them in to a Data Grid within an application (WinForm).

What is the best approach / method of displaying the data.

I need to be able to run a filter to the data to reduce down the data set, ideas would be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be filtering the data in the database and retrieving only the (pre)filtered result set. If this set is still large, use [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx), but also rethink your design - if you want to display so much data, that you are getting into performance problems, you might be showing to much data for a user, too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to filtering you should also consider paging in the backend (your SP should handle paging)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the grid to the DataSet, using the DataSource property and a BindingSource component. The Forms designer can take care of the creation of the BindingSource for you.
The BindingSource has a Filter property that allows you to filter the content of the DataSet

EDIT: by the way, in data-bound mode, the DataGridView implicitly uses virtual mode, so you don't have to worry about having too many rows in the grid